# Transforming a long sum of products for efficient computation (based on spanning trees in a complete graph)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, graph-theory, summation, products

Let's say there is a set of $n$ real coefficients: $a_1,...,a_n$. My task is to calculate the value of a rather simple sum of `k` products: `x_1+x_2+...+x_k`, where `x_i=a_alpha*...*a_lambda`. In other words - each of the summed elements `x` is a product of `z` of the coefficients. This sum is very "regular": each of the coefficients appears equal number of times in the whole expression (they are combinatorically distributed among the summed elements, `n<<k`, `z<n`).
The problem is that the is so many elements to sum up that the straightforward calculation would take months to compute. I need a transformation that with which I could calculate the final value in minutes max. I have been trying to move it all to log space but nothing came up...

Comment: Is there any other structure besides "each coefficient appears an equal number of times"?  For instance is it actually a symmetric polynomial in $a_{\alpha},\ldots,a_{\lambda}$?

Comment: I don't see a product anywhere in your formulas. It would also probably help if you were more explicit about the combinatorial nature of the sum.

Comment: @ErickWong: Please look below. No, it is not a symmetric polynomial.
@JonathanZ: Sorry, I corrected the typo. The sum comes from a complete graph with `n` edges - each of the element in sum corresponds to a spanning tree and is a product of weights of all edges in this tree.

Comment: I can't answer this question, but I think you should add 'graph theory' to the tags, and change the title to include 'based on spanning trees in a complete graph' to attract the people who are most likely to be able to help.

Comment: So which spanning trees are you using? I assume it's not all possible ones, as that would make it a symmetric polynomial, right?

Comment: Do you just want https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_theorem ? (Or the weighted version which might not be clear from Wikipedia)

Comment: @JonathanZ I think the polynomial derived from the edges of all spanning trees is not quite symmetric.  Consider the $4$-vertex case.  Pick a term corresponding to a path of length $3$: there will be some pairs of edges that you can’t interchange without forming a cycle.  So exchanging the corresponding variables in that term yields a monomial that cannot appear in the original polynomial -> not invariant.

Comment: You're right, @ErickWong.